# Capture traditional events and report them using IProgress<T>

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, events, async-await

Suppose I have the following legacy service:

```cs
public interface ISomeService 
{
    event EventHandler<SomeEventArgs> SomethingHappened;

    void MakeSomethingHappen();
}
```

Now I have *another* service that relies on the one above, but uses async reporting, as follows:

```cs
public class OtherService : IOtherService
{
    public async Task DoSomethingElse(IProgress<SomeEventArgs> progress)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I need to capture the events triggered in `ISomeService` and report them in `OtherService` using `IProgress<T>`. My solution to this was:

```cs
public async Task DoSomethingElse(IProgress<SomeEventArgs> progress)
{
    void handleEvent(object sender, SomeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (progress != null)
            progress.Report(e);
    }

    _someService.SomethingHappened += progressHandler;

    try
    {
        _someService.MakeSomethingHappen();
    }
    finally
    {
       _someService.SomethingHappened -= progressHandler;
    } 
}
```

Are there any dangers/problems with this?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @gigiabbrescia My bad, just added the question at the end.

Comment: If `_someService` is shared with another process, then all consumers will receive the same events which might be bad. Other than that, this question is really too opinion-based to be useful on here.

Comment: That's a good point about the consumers. Regarding the question being opinion based, I don't see how that is. Either what's on display is dangerous and it can be pointed out as you just did, or it is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no problem with consuming an event by a `Progress<T>` object. The only problem would be a possible memory leak in case you forgot to unsubscribe from the event, but your code takes care of that.

I would also like to point out that if you want to get fancy you could do the same thing in a reactive way, by using an [`IObservable<SomeEventArgs>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iobservable-1) as an intermediate propagator:

```
public async Task DoSomethingElse(IProgress<SomeEventArgs> progress)
{
    using var subscription = Observable
        .FromEventPattern<SomeEventArgs>(
            h => _someService.SomethingHappened += h,
            h => _someService.SomethingHappened -= h)
        .Select(ep => ep.EventArgs)
        .Subscribe(progress.ToObserver());

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        _someService.MakeSomethingHappen();
    });
}
```

The [`FromEventPattern`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh229251(v=vs.103)), [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh244306(v=vs.103)) and [`ToObserver`](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/9f2a8090cea4bf931d4ac3ad071f4df147f4df50/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Observer.Extensions.cs#L395) are extension methods defined in the [System.Reactive](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive/) package.

Comment: Very cool stuff! I'll look into it. I think this answers my question.

Answer (score -1):

Is there a reason you're avoiding Lambda functions? I can't think of any immediate problem with this solution (aside from binding the event to a local handler which may keep the parent in memory even when "MakeSomethingHappen" results in "_someService" own demise).

Still, for the sake of readability, I would go with Lambda handler...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you mean assigning a lambda function after the +=? How would I unsubscribe the event then? Btw in real code, I have a `try { ... } finally { ... }`; I unsubscribe the event in the `finally` block.

Comment: You don't need to unsubscribe there. In case you'd want lambda to no longer operate, you could simply verify a "variable" defined in the class (e.g. "DoNotProcessEvent == true") to exit the lambda before the rest of lambda is executed.